# MySQL Pivoting Rows to Dynamic Columns

Tags: mysql, select, dynamic, pivot-table, rows

we have a table that include people entrance/exit records as follow :

| Person | Day | Time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 02/21/2021 | 08:10 |
| 2 | 02/21/2021 | 08:11 |
| 1 | 02/21/2021 | 08:45 |
| 1 | 02/21/2021 | 09:18 |
| 1 | 02/21/2021 | 10:45 |
| 7 | 02/21/2021 | 10:53 |
| 2 | 02/21/2021 | 17:06 |
| 1 | 02/21/2021 | 17:23 |
| 7 | 02/21/2021 | 17:31 |
| 1 | 02/22/2021 | 08:13 |
| 5 | 02/22/2021 | 08:19 |
| 2 | 02/22/2021 | 08:20 |
| 2 | 02/22/2021 | 08:23 |
| 5 | 02/22/2021 | 09:47 |
| 5 | 02/22/2021 | 11:03 |
| 5 | 02/22/2021 | 18:06 |
| 5 | 02/22/2021 | 19:08 |
| 2 | 02/22/2021 | 19:01 |
| 5 | 02/22/2021 | 22:37 |
| 5 | 02/23/2021 | 08:15 |
| 1 | 02/23/2021 | 08:15 |
| 1 | 02/23/2021 | 14:30 |
| 5 | 02/23/2021 | 17:05 |

with these data, we want to select them as follow :

| Person | Day | Time1 | Time2 | Time3 | Time4 | Time5 | Time6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 02/21/2021 | 08:10 | 08:45 | 09:18 | 10:45 | 17:23 |  |
| 2 | 02/21/2021 | 08:11 | 17:06 |  |  |  |  |
| 7 | 02/21/2021 | 10:53 | 17:31 |  |  |  |  |
| 1 | 02/22/2021 | 08:13 |  |  |  |  |  |
| 2 | 02/22/2021 | 08:20 | 08:23 | 19:01 |  |  |  |
| 5 | 02/22/2021 | 08:19 | 09:47 | 11:03 | 18:06 | 19:08 | 22:37 |
| 1 | 02/23/2021 | 08:15 | 14:30 |  |  |  |  |
| 5 | 02/23/2021 | 08:15 | 17:05 |  |  |  |  |

Comment: Consider storing date and time as a single entity, and consider handling issues of data display in application code

Comment: Enumerate rows over a person+date then pivot.

Comment: could you write me how ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution is not to do this in SQL, but to just fetch all the data with a simple query:

```
SELECT person, day, time FROM WeHaveATable ORDER BY day, person, time;
```

Then write application code to present it in a grid however you want.

The reason that this is tricky in SQL is that SQL requires you spell out all the columns in the select-list before you prepare the query. That's before it gets a chance to read the data to know how many columns there would be for the person with the greatest number of times.

There is no way in SQL to generate "dynamic columns" by reading the data and appending more columns to the select-list based on what it discovers while reading data.

So the way to do a pivot in SQL is that you first must know how many columns.

```
SELECT MAX(c) FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM WeHaveATable GROUP BY person) AS t;
```

Then form a query that numbers the rows per person/day using a window function, and use that in a pivot-table query, with one column for each time, up to the max number of times you got in the previous query.

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT person, day, time, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY day, person ORDER BY time) AS colno
  FROM WeHaveATable;
)
SELECT day, person,
  MAX(CASE colno WHEN 1 THEN time END) AS Time1,
  MAX(CASE colno WHEN 2 THEN time END) AS Time2,
  MAX(CASE colno WHEN 3 THEN time END) AS Time3,
  MAX(CASE colno WHEN 4 THEN time END) AS Time4,
  MAX(CASE colno WHEN 5 THEN time END) AS Time5,
  MAX(CASE colno WHEN 6 THEN time END) AS Time6
FROM cte
GROUP BY day, person;
```

If this seems like a lot of confusing, meticulous work, you're right. That's why it's recommended to skip solving this in SQL. Do the simple query I showed at the top, then write application code to process the results into the grid like you want.

Comment: Assuming we have a maximum of 10 columns and that there is a need for pagination and sorting, isn't this method more efficient than the method done in the application?

Comment: Maybe. There's enough variation in performance from case to case that the only way to be sure is to try it both ways on your server with your data.

Answer (score 0):

For a data-driven list of column needs, see  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pivot

It builds the `SELECT` and optionally runs it.